# PowerShell + WebAdministration - How to get website from webapplication?

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7.5

I'm writing a PowerShell script to perform certain administrative functions in IIS 7.5.

```
import-module WebAdministration
```

In some cases I know the name of the web application I want to work with but not the web site it is under. Getting the application is easy:

```
$app = get-webapplication -name 'MyApp'
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the name of the web site given the app. It doesn't seem to be a property off the webapplication object. Best I could come up with was trying to get it via test-path:

```
get-website | where {test-path "iis:\sites\$_.name\MyApp"}
```

For some reason that comes up empty. Any thoughts on how to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how you can get the site name:

```
$siteName = (Get-WebApplication -name 'YourApp').GetParentElement().Attributes['name'].Value
```

Or even shorter:

```
$siteName = (Get-WebApplication -name 'YourApp').GetParentElement()['name']
```

Comment: This does not work in Powershell 7 + WindowsCompatibility:

InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#site#application] does not contain a method named 'GetParentElement'.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't dug into why, but if you use an asterisk or question mark anywhere in the string it works like a wildcard and returns as such.

I.E.

```
get-website -name '*myapp'

   Name      ID   State    Physical Path        Bindings
   ----      --   -----    -------------        --------

   myapp     12   Started  C:\inetpub\wwwroot   http:*:80:
  amyapp     13   Stopped  C:\anetpub\          http:*:81:
 aamyapp     14   Stopped  C:\another\place     http:172.198.1.2:80:host.header.com
```

or

```
get-website -name '?myapp'

Name   ID State   Physical Path Bindings
----   -- -----   ------------- --------
amyapp 13 Stopped C:\anetpub    http:*:81:
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$app = get-webapplication -name 'MyApp'
foreach($a in $app)
{
$a.Attributes[0].Value;
}
```

This will give you all the names of the Web Applications, sometimes you can have more than 1 name for a single Web Applications.

For more information see the link

http://nisanthkv.blog.com/2012/07/06/name-of-web-applications-using-powershell/

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Why is this so complicated and convoluted?!

This should *just* work:

$WebApplicationExists = ( Get-WebApplication | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $WebAppName } | Measure-Object ).Count -gt 0

This works:

$WebApplicationExists = ( Get-WebApplication -Name $WebAppName | Measure-Object ).Count -gt 0

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      17763  3770