# Unable to access object properties in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell v2.0 and the ActiveDirectory module on a windows 7 x64 machine to get a specific OU and then get users in that ou to do something with them. It works fine outside of a function such as below:

```
$ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Where {$_.Name -eq "<ou name>"}
Get-ADUser -Filter * | where {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*" + $ou.DistinguishedName} | sort SamAccountName | foreach{ Get-IMSGroup $_.SamAccountName} | ft -AutoSize
```

however, I wanted to make this easier by wrapping it in a function. After putting it in a function such as this it no longer works.

```
function Display-ImsUsersGroups([String]$OuName)
{
    $ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Where {$_.Name -eq $OuName}
    Get-ADUser -Filter * | where {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*" + $ou.DistinguishedName} | sort SamAccountName | foreach{ Get-IMSGroup $_.SamAccountName} | ft -AutoSize
}
```

Turns out the actual problem is that although $ou is getting initialized to the correct OU, I can't access the members, for example, `$ou.DistinguishedName` does not return anything and neither does `$ou.Name`.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570811/powershell-cmdlet-shows-property-but-it-cant-display-it-through-select), but when i run `$ou | Get-Member` I get the following output:

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit

Name                     MemberType            Definition                                           
----                     ----------            ----------                                           
Contains                 Method                bool Contains(string propertyName)                   
Equals                   Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                       
GetEnumerator            Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumer...
GetHashCode              Method                int GetHashCode()                                    
GetType                  Method                type GetType()                                       
ToString                 Method                string ToString()                                    
Item                     ParameterizedProperty Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyVal...
City                     Property              System.String City {get;set;}                        
Country                  Property              System.String Country {get;set;}                     
DistinguishedName        Property              System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}           
LinkedGroupPolicyObjects Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyVal...
ManagedBy                Property              System.String ManagedBy {get;set;}                   
Name                     Property              System.String Name {get;}                            
ObjectClass              Property              System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}                 
ObjectGUID               Property              System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=...
PostalCode               Property              System.String PostalCode {get;set;}                  
State                    Property              System.String State {get;set;}                       
StreetAddress            Property              System.String StreetAddress {get;set;}
```

Can anyone explain what I need to do to be able to access the properties?

Comment: Does your first statement perhaps return more than one OU? Try restricting `$ou` to a single object by adding `| select -First 1` to the statement.

Comment: Bingo, that was it, just happened to figure it out by accident (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, pretty much on accident I figured out the solution. It just so happens there were 2 OU's named what I was searching for and it was returning an array of objects. I somehow missed the fact that it was returning 2 results when displaying the object.

I was able to fix the problem by simply narrowing down my search so it would only return 1 OU.

Here's the corrected code:

```
$ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Where {($_.Name -eq $OuName) -and ($_.DistinguishedName -like "*<Distinguished Name of the parent OU>")} | select -First 1
```

I was able to limit my search this way since I only needed to get users within OUs that were in the same parent OU as this OU (Can you say that 5 times fast?)