# Does Get-WebApplication returns invalid objects?

Tags: powershell

Why do I don't get valid names, if I use Get-WebApplication in PowerShell like this:

```
Get-WebApplication  |  ForEach-Object { write-host $_.Name }
```

In the result set, the name properties are empty. Why?

Instead Get-WebApplication does return a structure like:

```
PS> Get-WebApplication 

Name             Application pool   Protocols    Physical Path                                                        
----             ----------------   ---------    -------------    
test             default            http         C:\....
```

Comment: ``get-webapplication | get-member`` and paste the output

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570811/powershell-cmdlet-shows-property-but-it-cant-display-it-through-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Get-WebApplication` is https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790554.aspx.

Name column in the output from `Get-WebApplication` seems to behave a little like a calculated property. I was unable to find out exactly what the formula is behind it but by running

```
Get-WebApplication | select -ExpandProperty Path | select @{ n="Name";e={ $_.TrimStart('/') } }
```

you will get a similar looking result as to what you appear to be trying to extract.

This command selects and simplifies the Path property (essentially turns it into a string), then creates from it a calculated property that has the correct title and value.

Comment: It is a calculated property and you can find an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571160/1158313