# Powershell IIS automation

Tags: powershell, iis, automation

I am a powershell noob. I am trying to learn it.

I want to get the physical path of the IIS website. i.e. if I have a website on my IIS I wish to get the physical path of the website and try to rename a text file in the directory.

I tried the below commands but did not help.

```
$siteName = (Get-WebApplication -name 'YourApp').GetParentElement()['PhysicalPath']
```

or

```
(Get-Website -Name "Default Web Site").PhysicalPath
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: I think this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504027/powershell-webadministration-how-to-get-website-from-webapplication) has an answer to your question

Comment: I obviously have gone through that and does not work properly. Thank you for the pointer and shall revisit the post and do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the module `WebAdministration` using the [Import-Module](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141553) cmdlet. Then you get the (text file) item using the [Get-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113319) cmdlet and finally rename it using [Rename-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382).

Here an example which renames a file named `file.txt` to `myfile.txt` for the `MyApplication` site within the `Default Web Site`:

```
import-module WebAdministration
Get-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\MyApplication\file.txt' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName 'myfile.txt'
```